# Vercel - `ZLIB_1.2.9' not found

Tags: node.js, npm, canvas, vercel

I am trying to use [canvas](https://www.npmjs.com/package/canvas) in a server less function on Vercel, but am running into an error I don't know how to get around:

`Error: /lib64/libz.so.1: version` ZLIB_1.2.9' not found (required by /var/task/api/node_modules/canvas/build/Release/libpng16.so.16)`

I have this in my package.json, but it appears to installed zlib 1.2.7:

```
  "scripts": {
    "vercel-build": "yum install libuuid-devel libmount-devel zlib && cp /lib64/{libuuid,libmount,libblkid,libz}.so.1 node_modules/canvas/build/Release/"
  },
```

As I see this in the build log `zlib-1.2.7-18.amzn2.x86_64 already installed and latest version`

How can I install 1.2.9 instead?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you found a solution but in case this is useful to anyone, downgrading `canvas` to `v2.6.1` helped in my case. downgrading canvas might also require using `node 14x` instead of `node 16` or higher because `node-gyp` tends to throw errors if you try to install `canvas 2.6.1` on `node 16` or higher.

Also might want to attach the build command to the additional vercel script.
Like: `"yum install libuuid-devel libmount-devel zlib && cp /lib64/{libuuid,libmount,libblkid,libz}.so.1 node_modules/canvas/build/Release/ && npm run build"`.